# wordpress Theme is duplicated my page sections

Tags: html, wordpress, duplicates

well, I assuming that my wordpress theme is doing that, but I really dont know.
Today I woke up and I was going to continue working on my home page and I saw that some sections are duplicate and I didnt do that.
Its a site with a woocomerce shop and I have an element that is "featured products" when I add it to the layout it duplicates itself. The same happens with all that is below that (instagram caroussel and fotter) 
Its like my wordpress added another new page below the home.
This is the page:
https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3F3.png)(also I upload an image)
I dont know what happenned.

This is some of the code that is at the bottom of the page

https://jsfiddle.net/ba2gwnyt/

```
<div class="vc_row-full-width"></div>
<div class="noo-container-fluid">
  <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
      <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
          <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  vc_custom_1559324189503">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
              <h1 style="text-align: left;"><b> PRODUCTOS DESTACADOS </b></h1>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="vc_separator wpb_content_element vc_separator_align_center vc_sep_width_100 vc_sep_dotted vc_sep_pos_align_center vc_separator_no_text vc_sep_color_black"><span class="vc_sep_holder vc_sep_holder_l"><span class="vc_sep_line"></span></span><span class="vc_sep_holder vc_sep_holder_r"><span class="vc_sep_line"></span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="noo-simple-product-wrap">
            <ul class="noo-simple-product-slider owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
              <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
                <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 2928px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 800ms ease 0s; transform: translate3d(-366px, 0px, 0px);">
                  <div class="owl-item" style="width: 366px;">
                    <li>
                      <a href="https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/tienda/accesorios/bille-triptica-oso/" class="hover-device">
                        <div class="noo-simple-slider-item">
                          <img width="650" height="650" src="https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/billeteraOso5-650x650.jpg" class="attachment-noo-thumbnail-product size-noo-thumbnail-product wp-post-image wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/billeteraOso5-650x650.jpg 650w, https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/billeteraOso5-150x150.jpg 150w, https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/billeteraOso5-32x32.jpg 32w, https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/billeteraOso5-100x100.jpg 100w"
```

I already tried to:
-create a new page and the same happened
- get back to and other revision and the same happened
-Delete some of my css to see if that was the reason
-Deactivate plugins

I hope someone can help me
thanks!

Comment: I guess you would need some expert to see your backend for this.

Comment: I think you need to check how these sections are built. Maybe there are some `shortcodes` that are called on the footer sections. If you could share your website URL we might get an idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress when you create a page it inherits the layout from the single.php file of your theme, And that is the reason why it's getting duplicated.

So if you want to create a different page then look for "How to make custom page template tutorial which suits your needs"
[Check this one for complete beginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)

Or just search it over bing or google.

Comment: Thank you Khalid I started over with a new template and everything looks good now

Comment: Great ! Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Go into your footer.php first and then index.php

On each page you're going to check that you don't have the following code duplicated. Or duplicated loops or references on these page.

```php
include()
include_once()
require()
require_once()
get_template_part()
```

**Also:**
If nothing seems off in the code you may want to check Elementor builder since the duplicated code is generated from Elementor.